# Trying to do a server side redirect using Java spring boot but the page stays blank on the front end even though it is reaching the external site

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

One of these web apps (marketing-dashboard) runs on my local server. The front end is in react the back end is in Java.

The other web app is on aws (AWS-dashboard).

I want for the user when they enter a specific url (localhost:300/marketing-dashboard/#/mdash) on my marketing dashboard to be able to get redirected to the external aws web app.

The problem that I am facing though is that even though it does look like the back end is reaching the site just fine with a 200. I saw it in the network console on my browser. The page on the server side web app (marketing-dashboard) just stays blank.

Here is my font end code:

```js
 function RedirectComponent() {

    fetch("/marketing-dashboard/awsRedirect")
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log("redireccted");
        } else {
          // Handle the error response here
          console.log("Something not right");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle any network errors here
        console.log(error);
      });

    return null;
  }
```

```html
{props.history.location.hash === "#/mdash" && <RedirectComponent />}
          </div>
```

This is my backend code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dmd-dashboard/arre", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void method(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "https://marketing-projects.marketing.my-net.dev.aws.mexp.com/mdash/index.html");
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
}
```

The reason I don't want to do a redirect from the front end is because I will have to send headers later down the road